# Spring Apache disable socket connection retry attempts

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, resttemplate

I am trying to disable some default behavior from the apache http client in a spring application.
Seems like the socket connection is being retried two more times upon failing.

I have extracted below from logs:

```
[2022-02-23 14:58:47.490]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connection request: [route: {s}->  <URL>[total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
[2022-02-23 14:58:47.490]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connection leased: [id: 937][route: {s}->  <URL>[total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
[2022-02-23 14:58:47.490]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Opening connection {s}->  <URL>:2350
[2022-02-23 14:58:47.508]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting to   <URL 1>:2350
[2022-02-23 14:58:47.508]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting socket to   <URL 1>:2350 with timeout 2000
[2022-02-23 14:58:49.510]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connect to   <URL 1>:2350 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
[2022-02-23 14:58:49.510]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting to   <URL 2>
[2022-02-23 14:58:49.510]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting socket to   <URL 2> with timeout 2000
[2022-02-23 14:58:51.512]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connect to   <URL 2> timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
[2022-02-23 14:58:51.512]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting to   <URL 3>
[2022-02-23 14:58:51.512]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connecting socket to   <URL 3> with timeout 2000
[2022-02-23 14:58:53.515]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - http-outgoing-937: Shutdown connection
[2022-02-23 14:58:53.515]   [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] [AsyncComparatorThread - 6]    - Connection discarded
```

You can see in the logs the 2 retry attempts. I want to disable this behavior and have only 1 try, but I am not sure which setting to use.

I have tried several approaches, first by making an HttpClient with disabledAutoRetries like:

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().disableAutomaticRetries().build();
```

Didn't work.
Then I tried to implement a custom RequestRetryHandler to return false always:

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().disableAutomaticRetries().setRetryHandler(retryHandler).build();
```

This also didn't work.

Any idea how I can disable this behavior ?
Note:
I am using only the defaults. Here is rest template configuration:

```
 HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

**EDIT**:
Managed to find the culprit for this behaviour. Inspecting the class DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator, I noticed connection is done in a for loop, looping over InetAddress array, which is an output of the DnsResolver. In the default DnsResolver, it returns an array of all IPs associated with host.
Here is the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < addresses.length; ++i) {
                InetAddress address = addresses[i];
                boolean last = i == addresses.length - 1;
                Socket sock = sf.createSocket(context);
                sock.setSoTimeout(socketConfig.getSoTimeout());
                sock.setReuseAddress(socketConfig.isSoReuseAddress());
                sock.setTcpNoDelay(socketConfig.isTcpNoDelay());
                sock.setKeepAlive(socketConfig.isSoKeepAlive());
                ...
                ...
                conn.bind(sock);
                ...
 }
```

Here is the DefaultDnsResolver:

```
public InetAddress[] resolve(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
        return InetAddress.getAllByName(host);
    }
```

I got rid of the retries from the log by replacing the DefaultDnsResolver with a custom one that fetches only 1 IP:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public HttpRequestRetryHandler requestRetryHandler() {
    return ((exception, executionCount, context) -> false);
  }

  @Bean
  public DnsResolver dnsResolver() {
    return ((s -> new InetAddress[] {InetAddress.getByName(s)}));
  }
}
```

This way, only 1 connection is performed.
In my case, the host had 3 associated IPs hence having 3 connection retries. Could anyone elaborate if changing this behavior can result in failed connections, who knows the details of InetAddress.getByName() method?

Comment: Try this : DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false);
((AbstractHttpClient)httpClient).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);

Comment: Tried above, getting actual error: org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient

Comment: Ok, I didn't noticed that AbsactHttlClient is depracated. Setting retry hadler when creating httpclient shoud do the work. Can you post code you used for retryHandler?

Comment: I added an "Edit" to above. Found a solution by changing the DnsResolver to return only 1 ip (it was returning all associated IPs). Also posted code for retryHandler, which just always returns false